# Cat a file with a variable name present in it

Tags: shell, unix

```
var=`date`

pg_dump -U postgres database_name > ~/database_backups/database_name.backup.${var}

new_item_id=$(cat ~/database_backups/database_name.backup.${var}| grep "Item" | awk '{print($1);exit}’)
```

cat: /Users/karanj/database_backups/database_name.backup.: No such file or directory

Comment: You'll get *an* error if you don't quote `${var}`, but I don't see how you would get *that* error unless the output of `date` somehow contains leading whitespace.

Comment: The default output of `date` is pretty verbose, and does not sort naturally. use something like this: `datetime=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` or truncate to whatever datetime granularity you require.